# Regex search to Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, regex

I made this to track my variable changes while I experiment in Python. I tend to use the same variable names and fit different values to them so it's nice to be able to see what I've tried, especially if I'm constructing a huge code block.

I copy text onto my clipboard before starting this code.The code asks for the variables to track, then creates a Regex fitting my usual variable definition for each variable:

```
' variable_name = '
```

It then searches text pasted by Pyperclip with `re.findall` to create a list of bindings for each name, which is then written to an Excel spreadsheet for easier reading of the changes to definitions over time.

```
import re, pyperclip, openpyxl
wb= openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
```

Setting up - importing modules, creating a new workbook

```
print("Please input definitions/name bindings you want to track, separated"
      " by ', '")
names = input().split(', ')
```

Creating a list of names to track

```
regexlist = []
for name in names:
    regexlist.append(re.compile(r'(?<=\s' + name + r'\s=\s).*'))
```

Making a list of Regexes that will be used to search for the text following variable definitions. Note each Regex in the list should share the same index as 
the name in the list 'names'.

```
text = pyperclip.paste()
c = 1          # column number, changes with iteration
for i, regex in enumerate(regexlist):
    changelist = regex.findall(text)
    ws.cell(row=1, column=c, value=names[i]) # Header is variable name
    for i, binding in enumerate(changelist):
        ws.cell(row=i+2, column=c, value=binding)
    c += 1     # move to next column for next variable
print('variable tables created, input filename as filename.xlsx')
file = input()
wb.save(file)
```

The eventual goal is to move towards having it read from the files (sys.stdout? for example) but at this stage I don't have the capability to do it, nor the need so I'm just looking to fine tune this in case I've missed out any possibilities.